Calling a Flutter closure from JavaScript using js_interop
I have a method in Flutter that receives a closure. I want to pass that closure to JS and call it back anytime, from somewhere in JS. I'd also like to use dart:js_interop to be WASM compatible (I have seen an example using setProperty and allowInterop but they come from dart:js which is deprecated).
typedef OnCallbackTFunction = void Function(bool something);

class MyClass {
    [...]
    // This method could be called more than once with different closures
    void doSomething({OnCallbackTFunctio? onSomething})
    {
        // On JS side I should store the [onSomething] closure to be called back.
        // Something like this(?):
        wasmSetCallback(onSomething);
    }
}

On JS I need something to store the callback. Well, this is a C++ class which uses EM_ASM to inline some JS code:
typedef void (*dartCallback_t)(bool something);

// Each call to the Dart `doSomething()` will create only one instance of this class.
class MyCallbackClass {
public:
    void setCallback(dartCallback_t *callback)
    {
        EM_ASM({
            // What to put here?
        });
    }
    
    void callDartMethod()
    {
        EM_ASM({
            // What to put here?
        });
    }
}

This C++ code will be compiled with emscripten to produce also the .js.
All this to achieve something like:
final n = MyClass.instance.doSomething(onSomething: () {print('callback N from JS!');});
final m = MyClass.instance.doSomething(onSomething: () {print('callback M from JS!');});

I read that JSObjectUnsafeUtilExtension could be used to set JS property, maybe a JS function to use for the callback, but I've not found docs explaining how to use it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
